# how to remove duplicates from reducers output?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

how to remove duplicates from reducer output?Reducer generating part-r-0000 file which contain a many duplicates values.i want to remove all duplicates value from this file.I am working on tweet analysis.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your job you have multiple possibilities.

**1) Multi Stage Job**

You can add another Map Reduce job which reads the result data. Calculates a hash on your value. The hash is the key which you want to send to the reducer in combination with all other information you want to write. Now you have all information for the same value in one reduce step. Do what you need to do with the iterable, just take the first or have a look at all, this depends on you specific use case.

**2) Secondary Sorting**

If you already know that a key holds all duplicate data but the data is to large for a simple set to be used. Than have a look at Secondary Sorting. This feature provides the possibility to sort the values of a key. Now you can simply skip the entries you already have written until a new one is coming.

Comment: Thanks Mattias Kricke :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a simple pig script: LOAD, DISTINCT, STORE.

Comment: I am Looking for map reduce solution.thanks bydway @facha